# UserPass Authentication Vault

Tags: spring-boot, hashicorp-vault, spring-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

I have been trying to use the authentication method from Hashicorp Vault (from [here](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/userpass.html)) in my application to get configurations.

But not able to get any information regarding this authentication type in Spring's docs, examples, etc. Can you please help me out as I need this type of authentication to help me with vault in multiuser environment.

Comment: Please share your code here...

Comment: I don't have any code regarding this, I just wanted to know if **spring-vault** or **spring-cloud-vault** implements all the authentication methods given by the **Hashicorp Vault's** authentication APIs or just the ones I can google because I'm trying to implement **Spring-cloud-config** methodology for my application using Vault.

Comment: Have you checked out the docs? https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/single/spring-cloud-vault.html#vault.config.authentication

Comment: Yes but it doesn't have the userpass authentication method. It has app-id method which is deprecated and replaced by approle, but the userpass method is different than the app-id/approle method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here is my solution:**

Configuration class:

```
package com.company.myapp.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.vault.VaultException;
import org.springframework.vault.authentication.ClientAuthentication;
import org.springframework.vault.support.VaultToken;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Configuration
public class VaultConfig {

    public static final String LOGIN_PATH = "/v1/auth/userpass/login/";

    @Bean
    public ClientAuthentication clientAuthentication(@Value("${VAULT_USERNAME}") String username,
                                                     @Value("${VAULT_PASSWORD}") String password,
                                                     @Value("${spring.cloud.vault.uri}") String host) {
        return new UserPassAuthentication(host, LOGIN_PATH, username, password);
    }

    public static class UserPassAuthentication implements ClientAuthentication {

        private RestOperations restOperations = new RestTemplate();

        private String url;

        private String password;

        public UserPassAuthentication(String host, String path, String user, String password) {
            this.url = new StringBuilder(host).append(path).append(user).toString();
            this.password = password;
        }

      @Override
    public VaultToken login() throws VaultException {
        return VaultToken.of(
                ((Map<String, String>) restOperations.postForEntity(url, new Password(password), Map.class)
                        .getBody().get("auth")).get("client_token"));
    }
}

static class Password {
    private String password;

    public Password(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

resources/bootstrap.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev

spring.application.name=myapp
spring.cloud.vault.kv.enabled=true
spring.cloud.vault.kv.backend=test-backend

spring.cloud.vault.uri=https://localhost:8200
VAULT_USERNAME=usr
VAULT_PASSWORD=pwd
```

resources/META-INF/spring.factories

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=com.company.myapp.config.VaultConfig
```

Comment: The above config throws `BeanDefinitionStoreException` as the bean clientAuthentication is already created by spring. Any other things to do apart from above code.

Answer (score 0):

Using this solution I had 2 problems.

1. overriding spring preconfigured beans.

solution: add

`spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding =true`

in your bootstrap.properties file. this allows bean definition overriding.

2. beanInstantiationException: Because authentication steps were not defined properly.
   solution: I used the token authentication method as follows:

   ```
    public ClientAuthentication clientAuthentication()  {
        return new TokenAuthentication(new UserPassAuthentication("host", path, "user", "password").login());
    }
   ```

and the rest of the code exactly as shown before.